# How to enable notifications correctly? Here is my failed attempt. (Java!)

Tags: android, android-fragments, permissions, android-notifications, android-permissions

There was a problem when creating Notifications in a Fragment when clicking on a button, or rather with permissions to them, I believe. I am newbie and trying to implement everything for the first time. (Java!)

Hi all! I'm trying to implement Notifications in a test application. According to the articles from the documentation, I am trying to restore the logical chain, but I did not succeed. THIS IS ALL DONE IN A FRAGMENT!

So first I add the required dependency.

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'`

Then I change the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
```

In my Fragment I declare a function for adding a channel:

```
private String CHANNEL_ID = "channelid";

private void createNotificationChannel() {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

This method is called in onViewCreated.

The notification should appear when the button is clicked, therefore (onViewCreated):

```
mainFragmBinding.notifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    showNotification();
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
```

showNotification():

```
private void showNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new
                NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle(getString(
                        R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            }
        notificationManager.notify(
                42, builder.build()
        );
            return;
        }
```

Next, as I believe, you need to define the logic, but what if the permission is not given?

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            }
```

But the required (?) method is deprecated:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE &&
                grantResults.length == 1) {
            if (
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                requestCode, permissions, grantResults
        );
    }
```

Maybe in that block if you need to call this method:

```
public void requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[] {
                        Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                },
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Where is the mistake and how to proceed? Help me please!

I need the ordinary notifications for now.